# How to show image from database to blade in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I will put the image with tag in database. It can be `svg` also.

Like this:

[image]

Now I want to show the image with for loop.

```
@foreach($plan as $plan)
 { !! html_entity_decode($plan->plan_image)  !! }
 or 
 {!! $plan->plan_image !! }
@endforeach
```

Not working. How can I resolve this?
Thanks

Comment: Firstly, the variables from your foreach has the same name, and second there is an space between !! and }.

Comment: what are the error you get?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the way to go with images and the database. This way you will have a very little space to do any kind of customization.

If your code is not working, you can always do `{{ dd($plan->plan_image) }}` and see what happens.

Also, you should stop using Blade's `or` and start using `??` PHP's native null coalesce operator.